# problem with access object property in typescript angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, spotify

I have a typescript object like this

```js
const playlist: { tracks: Array<Track> } = { tracks: new Array<Track>() };
```

And this is Track interface

```js
interface Track {
  title?: string;
  album?: string;
  artists?: string;
  duration?: string;
  explicit?: boolean;
  url?: string;
}
```

I'm trying to get data from [Spotify web API](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/) to my `playlist` object like this

```js
for (let i = 1; i <= iterationCount; i++) {
    const endpointX = `${BASE_API_URL}playlists/${playlistId}/tracks?limit=${PLAYLIST_ITEM_LIMIT}&offset=${i}&fields=${fieldString}`;
    const subscription: Subscription = this.http.get<WritableTrackList>(endpointX).subscribe(data => {
      for (const item of data.items) {
        const track: Track = this.helperService.trackApiObject2TrackObject(item.track);
        this.playlist.tracks.push(track);
      }
    });    
}
```

When I try to print `playlist` object in the javascript console with `console.log(this.playlist);`, it's working.
[image]

Buth I try to print `playlist.tracks` with `console.log(this.playlist.tracks);`, it's print an empty array

[image]

Why can't I access the `tracks` property of the `playlist` object? How can i access this property? Any solution?

Comment: If you see the console.log(this.playlist), it has tracks: Array(0) means there is no item in that array, also there is i icon in front of it, hover over on it you will see message. The list that you are seeing is temporary adn changed after console.log

Comment: When are you logging tracks property? Console.log is passed object reference. It might be possible that this.playlist is getting populated later. Can you try console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.playlist))) and see it still your list is populating?

Comment: @PankajSati I tried that. It is not displaying the list. It is displaying an empty list

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is Chrome's JavaScript console lazy about evaluating arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057440/is-chromes-javascript-console-lazy-about-evaluating-arrays)

Comment: @Hirusha Your list is getting populated inside of the subscription. Therefore, the values will become available only after that. There is no issue with this approach though if you intend to display/ modify items only when fetched.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
console.log(this.playlist['tracks']);
```

if you want to use like `this.playlist.tracks` you must declare an interface for playlist:

```
interface PlayList{
tracks:Track[]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe try to print it inside the subscription.

```
    .subscribe(data => {
          for (const item of data.items) {
            const track: Track = this.helperService.trackApiObject2TrackObject(item.track);
            this.playlist.tracks.push(track);
          }

console.log([...this.playlist.tracks])

        }); 

// printing outside subscription will most likely give an empty array
```

although in general you would want something reactive

```
tracks$ = this.http.get<WritableTrackList>(endpointX).pipe(map(trackApiObject2TrackObject));
```

then in the template

```
<ng-template ngFor let-track[ngForOf]="tracks$| async">
<app-track [track]></app-track>
</ng-template>
```